# communication between Cordova UWP app and windows desktop app

Tags: cordova, uwp

I have written an app in JavaScript/Cordova and compiled it to a Windows UWP app. I also have a third-party windows desktop app. I would like to open the desktop app from my Cordova app, passing it a parameter and pass a value back to my Cordova app from the desktop app on some event (e.g. when the desktop app closes). The desktop app has an API - so if my app had been written in say .NET this would not be a problem. Is there any way to achieve what I want? I assume the fact that one app is desktop and one is UWP makes it impossible for the two apps to interact directly? What if the third party produce a UWP version of their app? 
Martin

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to open the desktop app from my Cordova app, passing it a parameter and pass a value back to my Cordova app from the desktop app on some event (e.g. when the desktop app closes). The desktop app has an API - so if my app had been written in say .NET this would not be a problem. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

When you build a cordova app for windows platform. It will be built into a 100% UWP(JS) app. So you can consider Cordova app is a UWP app when in windows platform. So, it is not possible to open a desktop app.

The way of communication between UWP app and desktop app is through [App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service). But still, it can't open your desktop app.

Updates:

In Cordova UWP App, you can call WinRT directly like below:

```
var AppServices = Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService;
var conn = new AppServices.AppServiceConnection();
```

But in cordova app there will be no intellisense support for that, which makes it difficult for coding, you can create a test UWP(JS) app, write the codes and copy past codes to your cordova app.

Comment: Thanks Elvis. You say UWP can communicate with a desktop app through app service, but the link you supply says "Learn how to write a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app that can provide a service to other UWP apps". Can a UWP app provide a service to a desktop app too? Also, I wonder how I could add an App service to my JavaScript/HTML app since it only becomes a UWP app after Cordova has compiled it. I can write a plugin that calls a Windows runtime component - could that component be or could it call call an App Service ?

Comment: You can call WinRT APIs directly in Desktop Apps. Please refer to [Enhance your desktop application for Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-enhance). JavaScript Cordova App in UWP platform can consume WinRT directly with full namespace, please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Your Cordova/UWP app can launch your desktop application via protocol launch:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_

For that to work the desktop app needs to register a protocol for itself. For example: MS WORD registers the "ms-word:" protocol, so you can launch MS WORD from your UWP via LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-word:").

Comment: hi. is it possible to send data from one Cordova/UWP app and receive the same in another Cordova/UWP app?

Comment: @ParthDoshi Yes - would be best to open a new question though for new topics